# Why are my mobile menu links not working when targeted to a specific section on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Why are my mobile links only bringing me to the homepage and not the specific section I am linking them to?

Mobile Menu:

`

```
<nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services </a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

`

Body:

`

```
<section id="about" class="about-h1"> 

<section id="services" class="no-padding services-h1">

<section id ="contact" class="cb-h1 no-padding">
```

`

Comment: The code you've posted (except for the missing section close tags) is correct. Do you have any JavaScript, other code or browser plugins that may be interfering? Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/u3zne3g4/1/

Comment: There could be javascript interfering with the template of code I am editing. How would the javascript be linked to this? What am I looking for?

Comment: Browsers automatically handle in-page anchor links (what you've done) natively without any help. JavaScript can be used to enhance/extend this behaviour. On the same note, it can disable it.

I'd be looking for something involving any combo of `preventDefault()`, `location.href`, `window.scrollTo`, `offsetTop`(left/bottom/right).

I'd also look at any JavaScript libraries you've got linked, and learn what they do on the page to see if they do anything affecting page navigation or link actions.

Comment: More specifically, you could try looking for something that occurs on a hyperlink click event. Potential code sample (in jQuery): `$('a').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault() });` - this is one example of JS that could cause the problem you're describing.